# extra fields in django-userena, cannot retrieve value from a form

Tags: django

Trying to use `django-userena` for one of my projects. But have problems with retrieving the value of one of the form fields.

My form looks like as following (almost same with demo, only `phone` field is added):

```
class SignupFormExtra(SignupForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label=_(u'First name'), max_length=30, required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Last name'), max_length=30, required=False)
    phone = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Phone'), max_length=15, required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(SignupFormExtra, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        # Put the first and last name at the top
        new_order = self.fields.keyOrder[:-2]
        new_order.insert(0, 'first_name')
        new_order.insert(1, 'last_name')
        self.fields.keyOrder = new_order

    def save(self):
        # First save the parent form and get the user.
        new_user = super(SignupFormExtra, self).save()

        new_user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        new_user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        new_user.save()

        user_profile = new_user.get_profile()
        user_profile.user = new_user
        user_profile.phone_number = self.cleaned_data['phone']
        user_profile.save()

        return new_user
```

Now when I fill-in the fields in signup form and click 'Submit', I got following error:

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
115. response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/userena/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
28. return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/userena/views.py" in signup
119. user = form.save()
File "/home/qwerty/dev/projects/qqq/accounts/forms.py" in save
50. user_profile.phone_number = self.cleaned_data['phone'] # problem is here

Exception Type: KeyError at /accounts/signup/
Exception Value: 'phone'
```

So strange thing here is that `self.cleaned_data['phone']` is always being empty, even if I input data, however there is no problems with accessing `last_name` and `first_name`. I couldn't find any solution for the problem, I would be grateful if anyone could show me the right path.

Comment: By doing `self.fields.keyOrder[:-2]` you are actually leaving out the last two fields. You should not slice the list.

Comment: Thanks Aamir, your suggestion solved my problem. If you add this as an answer, I will choose it as a 'selected'.

Comment: Posted as an answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `self.fields.keyOrder[:-2]` you are actually leaving out the last two fields. You should not slice the list.

```
new_order = self.fields.keyOrder
```

Comment: I just removed `__init__` method.